# bash each two elements into array

Tags: arrays, bash, split

I have text and each line breaker, I store it the value in array and I display it :

```
var=("AAA
      aaa
      BBB
      bbb
      CCC
      ccc")

SAVEIFS=$IFS
 IFS=$'\n'
var=($var)
IFS=$SAVEIFS

for (( i=0; i<${#var[@]}; i++ )) do
  echo "${var[$i]}"
done
```

output :

```
   AAA
   aaa
   BBB
   bbb
   CCC
   ccc
```

but I want two first element in the same index array with the line breaker inside each element, like that

```
 var[0]=("AAA
         aaa")
  var[1]=("BBB
         bbb")
   var[2]=("CCC
         ccc")
```

Comment: Why is `var` an array when it has only a single element? Just use `var=("AAA" "aaa" "BBB" "bbb" "CCC" "ccc")`. If that string comes from an external source and you have to split it by line, use `readarray -t var <<< "$str"` instead of `var=("$str")`.

Comment: Then it's just a matter of array slicing. `var2+=("${var[*]:i:2}")` for i=0,2,4,....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare the array using bash [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)

```
ary=($'AAA\naaa' $'BBB\nbbb' $'CCC\nccc')
```

Then you get what you are after.

Inspecting the contents of the array

```
$ declare -p ary
declare -a ary='([0]="AAA
aaa" [1]="BBB
bbb" [2]="CCC
ccc")'
```

Or inspect it with printf:

```
$ printf '>%s<\n' "${ary[@]}"
>AAA
aaa<
>BBB
bbb<
>CCC
ccc<
```

---

You can't write

```
 var[0]=("AAA
         aaa")
```

because, with the parentheses, you are attempting to store an array in an array element, and bash does not allow arrays-of-arrays.

You *could* write

```
var=(
"AAA
aaa"
"BBB
bbb"
"CCC
ccc"
)
```

---

If you have an array of words like `var=(AAA aaa BBB bbb CCC ccc)` then you  could group elements together like this:

```
ary=()
for (( i=0; i < ${#var[@]}; i+=2 )); do
    ary+=( "${var[i]}"$'\n'"${var[i+1]}" )
done
```